# Php query returns no rows with varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table where the user column is a varchar.

This works with an int type

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
```

But when I try to match a varchar, nothing gets returned.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE user='$username'");
```

I've tried to strip the values and still nothing.

any suggestions?

Comment: `user='".trim($username)."'"` ?

Comment: How are your columns labeled? It sounds like you may have user='$username' and you want it to be name='$username' or you want to SELECT user.

Comment: I suggest you try the query first in command line or PHPMyAdmin and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

I typically use something like this. (plus some sanitization)

```
$username = strtolower($username);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE LCASE(user)='{$username}'");
```

This will get you the username no matter how they type it by making the case identical.

Since you are using `=` it has to be an exact match. Otherwise you would use `LIKE`.

The code I provided above will return the exact match of the username. 
This code will force the `$username` to all lowercase, then we can do the same for MySQL using `LCASE`. Now you can have an identical match.

The problem you may have been having was that `userName` is not the same as `UserName` or even `UsErNaMe`. Make sure when you do an exact match that the case is the same too.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would manipulate this. $sql = sprintf("select * from mytable where username = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string(trim($q)));

Comment: ```$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LCASE(username) = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower(trim($q))))``` should work